# How to debug protractor script using Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, protractor

From command line, protractor is run by typing `protractor conf.js` which in turn runs the script.

My conf.js looks like this:

```
  exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['animal_adoption_1.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

The error that I am getting is :

> js:
>   "C:\Users\Shikhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\ParamProc\conf.js",
>   line 2: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError:
>   "exports" is not defined.     at
>   C:\Users\Shikhar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\ParamProc\conf.js:2

I am using Eclipse Indigo as the IDE. Do I need to use Karma in order to do this or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the tests inside of Eclipse? It looks like you are invoking node and passing `conf.js` as the script to run.

Make sure that you are invoking `protractor` and passing `conf.js` to it.

Comment: Thanks Andrew , can you please add a snapshot or step how to do that.